# How do I print a complete http request on C# Xamarin

Tags: http, xamarin, printing, request, output

I'm having some random errors on encoding returned by the server side.

I was wondering how can I output an entire request (using HttpClient class) before it is sent. I haven't found how to do this anywhere.

thanks

Comment: Anyone? 

This seems to be a simple thing... i'm fustrated that I can't figure it out...